# Group values stores against time in SQL (maria DB) until Zero and do a summation along with count

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, cumulative-sum, gaps-and-islands

I have SQL table which has data stored in 15min intervals against a variable(unique key). The value can be any number for each interval of time including zero. Wanted to group the values until zero against the unique key.

Like if the values are 0,0,100,900,30,0,0,0,400,900,100,0,0,0,0,400,500,0,0 over time wanted to add values until zero (like sum as 1030, 1400, 900, ... ) against each unique key and also count number of instances the values are not zero (like in this case it is 3 & so on).

We have data stored in SQL (mariaDB) against time(15-min interval). Now this data determines the performance of an entity and it is secs (like number of secs within that 15min interval, it has issues wherein it can take any value from zero to 900). Now we are able to group them for any time interval period and plot the total impacted secs easily

Parameter_health Database contains two tables --

1. Parameter_detail table contains fixed data information against the parameter
2. Parameter_uasvalue table contains the un-available secs(UAS) for each 15 min interval against time for that parameter

I used the SQL query as below which is overall sum of the total UAS grouped to-gether but I would like to group them until next zero value and also count the total instance of such events (not non zero events but total incidents when it was not zero) for any interval.

Using the below query in Grafana

```
SELECT parameter_detail.system, parameter_detail.parameter_label, sum(parameter_uasvalue.uas) as 'Total UAS'
FROM parameter_health.parameter_uasvalue left join parameter_health.parameter_detail on parameter_detail.id=parameter_uasvalue.id
WHERE $__timeFilter(parameter_uasvalue.time) and parameter_uasvalue.uas != '-1' and parameter_uasvalue.uas !=' 0' 
GROUP BY parameter_detail.system, parameter_detail.parameter_label
```

Wanted to group each values until zero (do summation) and then count such instances for any time interval in sql query. Table structure of parameter_uasvalue table is shown below

```
id  time    uas
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 0:00 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 0:15 100
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 0:30 900
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 0:45 30
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 1:00 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 1:15 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 1:30 400
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 1:45 900
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 2:00 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 2:15 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 2:30 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 2:45 400
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 3:00 500
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 3:15 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 3:30 0
Parameter-Unique Value1 15/11/2021 3:45 0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPDCj.png)

Comment: Please share your table structure with sample value in tabular form.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Edited my query with the details you had requested for, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. It would be great if you can upload values in text format so that I can recreate the scenario.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur  Thanks, I have added it. Another table is other details of the parameter which is normally fixed info and we do join them in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of gaps and islands problem. First process and group `parameter_uasvalue` data then join `Parameter_detail`.

```
SELECT d.system, d.parameter_label, seriesStart, s, nonzc 
from (
    select id, min(time) seriesStart, sum(uas) s, count(case when uas > 0 then uas end) nonzc
    from (
      select id, time, uas, sum(flag) over(partition by id order by  time) grp
      from (
        select id, time, uas, (coalesce(lag(uas, 1) over(partition by id order by  time),0) = 0 and uas != 0) flag
        from parameter_health.parameter_uasvalue t
        where $__timeFilter(time) and uas != -1 
          -- it will break series detection 
          -- and uas != 0
      ) t
    ) t
    group by id, grp
) t
left join parameter_health.parameter_detail d on d.id=t.id
order by d.system, d.parameter_label, seriesStart;
```

[Grouping demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=73df34e9b233dee1ffa73280322a42b2)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am new to SQL, so I am confused on the statement provided, I am not sure which id I should be referring as indicated there are two tables with ID field, also where should I apply the actual time filter and what does 't' denote.  It would be great if you could guide me on the above.  I did try few options but I am getting error indicating error in sql query

Comment: @Ramanan, see the edited answer

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think i can use this though as we are facing Server timeout error with just 51 days of data and probably we might need to move it to Time series DB